# Use Solidworks Macro to Build Assembly of STL Files

Tags: vba, excel, solidworks

I am trying to write a macro in Solidworks (2015) to take a large group of .STL files, load them into Solidworks, and align them in an assembly.

Initially, I recorded a macro on solidworks of me doing just that. I would load a .STL file, create an assembly from it, then load other .STL files, save them, then add them to the assembly. The files **would align perfectly by themselves** (I think by using their relative position to the origin).

The recorded code looked something like this:

```
Dim swApp as Object
Dim boolstatus as Boolean
Dim longstatus as long, longwarnings as long

Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.Solidworks
boolstatus = swApp.LoadFile2("FileLocation", "r")
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Dim myModelView as Object
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameLeft = 0
myModelView.FrameTop = 22
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameWidth = 1845
myModelView.FrameHeight = 935
longstatus = Part.SaveAs3("SaveLocation", 0, 2)
Set Part = swApp.NewDocument("AssemblyLocation", 0, 0, 0)
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameWidth = 1845
myModelView.FrameHeight = 935
boolstatus = Part.AddComponent(".SLDPRTfilelocation", -8.034...E-05, 1.036...E-04, -2.799...E-05)
swApp.ActivateDoc2 "DocName", False, longstatus
swApp.CloseDoc "DocName"
'^Repeats for more .STL files (just adds to assembly doesn't make assembly for each file)
```

What is interesting about this recorded code is: 
1) Trying to run the recorded code doesn't work (the `.AddComponent` command doesn't seem to work unless I close the file then open it again with `.OpenDoc6`). 2) When a part is added to the assembly using `.AddComponent` it requires the x,y,z coordinates of the geometric centre of the part it is adding. When I record the macro of putting the parts into the assembly by hand one-at-a-time I can see the coordinates of the geometric centres of the .STL files.

The files perfectly align in the assembly using these values so it's safe to assume they are correct.

How does Solidworks determine these coordinate values? Is there any code I can use to determine them?

I have tried the code in ([A method to calculate the centre of mass from a .stl (stereo lithography) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083771/a-method-to-calculate-the-centre-of-mass-from-a-stl-stereo-lithography-file)), and while it seems to work for simple structures, when I produced the assemblies using this code the parts were not aligned. I also compared the x,y,z coordinates generated from this code to the values I saw in the recorded macro, and they did not match.

So, in brief, I want to create a macro to load many .STL files into a solidworks assembly and have the align automatically. I can do this correctly by hand but I don't know how Solidworks determines the geometric centers for each .STL file as it loads them into the assembly.

I'm pretty stuck at the moment, so any ideas you might have would be really appreciated!

Comment: FYI, the AddComponent() method is obsolete, you should use AddComponent5(CompName, ConfigOption, NewConfigName, UseConfigForPartReferences, ExistingConfigName, X, Y, Z) where XYZ are the coordinates of the component center.  The XYZ coordinates may differ from the assembly and the part.  I think that would require additional calculation.